# how to create zip from images base64 php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, zip

```
var imgAlums = window.document.getElementsByClassName("imgAlu");
var photos= [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgAlums.length; i++) {
        photos.push(imgAlums[i].currentSrc);
}
```

> //the photos array is filled 
>  //photos[0]=
>   data:image/*;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA...;
>
>   //photos[1]=data:image/*;base64,/9j/4AAFWEJDKWMDCIWUEIOD...;

```
$.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '<?= URL_PROYECTO_SEGURO ?>/panel/assets/php/generateZipPhotos.php',
                    data: {"photos": JSON.stringify(photos)},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        alert("Operacion realizada con exito");
                    }
                });
```

PHP code:

```
$nameZip = "test.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($nameZip, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addEmptyDir("Photos");
$photos= json_decode($_POST["photos"], true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {

$data = $photos[$i];
$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

$zip->addFromString("Photos/Photo" . $i . ".png", $data);
}

$zip->close();
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nameZip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($nameZip);
unlink($nameZip);
```

But does not generate the zip file correctly.

[edit]The zip file is generated but this has nothing inside. The problem is when you write in the zip file. The photo is misspelled

Comment: Do you have it installed/enabled on your server? http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

Comment: The zip file is generated but this has nothing inside. The problem is when you write in the zip file. The photo is misspelled